# Intuitively, why does the dot product of any point in the plane with the normal vector always give the same answer?

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, vectors, intuition

A few days ago I asked: [Help with Proposition $2.3.3$ from Elem. Differential Geometry by Pressley](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1468090/help-with-proposition-2-3-3-from-elem-differential-geometry-by-pressley)

But now I have a similar question:

---

If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are points on the plane, why does $\alpha \cdot \mathbf N= \beta \cdot \mathbf N$.  I know one answer is because $$(\alpha - \beta) \cdot \mathbf N=0$$
$$\alpha \cdot N = \beta \cdot N$$

But looking at it this way: $$\| \alpha\|\|\mathbf N\|\cos\theta_1 = \| \beta\|\|\mathbf N\|\cos\theta_2$$
$$\| \alpha\|\cos\theta_1=\| \beta\|\cos\theta_2$$

**Why does the dot product of any point in the plane (not vector ON the plane) with the normal vector always give the same answer?**

Answer (score 4):

Here is a picture.

[image]

$A$ and $B$ are points in the plane $P$, while $N$ is the subspace normal to $P$. Cleverly, I've called the origin $O$.

Recall that the dot product $A \cdot N$ is merely the length of the projection of $A$ onto $N$.

The green lines from $A$ and $B$ meet at the projection $\operatorname{proj}_N(A)$ of $A$ onto $N$ which just so happens to be the projection $\operatorname{proj}_N(B)$ of $B$ onto $N$.

The projections are the same, and hence have equal lengths. In other words, the dot products are equal.

Comment: Nice picture. But now I ask: Why are the two projections the same? Surely, $A$ and $B$ have different lengths.

Comment: Indeed they may, but remember that the projections we're talking about are *orthogonal* so $B$ gets "moved" along a path (the green line) that's orthogonal to $N$: its path stays in $P$. So the "paths" start in $P$, move orthogonally to $N$ (stay in $P$) and land on $N$: They must both end at the intersection of $N$ and $P$.

Answer (score 1):

Drop a perpendicular $d$  from the origin to the plane in question (it will be parallel to the normal). Then $$\| \alpha\|\cos\theta_1=\|d\|$$
for any $\alpha.$

Answer (score 0):

If the vector is IN the plane then it will always be orthogonal with the normal vector. That is how it is defined. So we can pick whatever vectors sitting in the plane we like and the normal vector will always pass through them perpindicularly so the angle between any vectors and the normal vector will be equal.

Comment: I am not talking about vectors in the plane. For any vector in the plane, dotting with $\mathbf N$ will always give $0$.

Comment: Then you need to change your question. "Why does the dot product of any vector in the plane with the normal vector always give the same answer?"

Comment: Caught that. Thanks. Fixed

Comment: Can you supply an updated answer? Thanks